# What does this statement do

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which contains a line of code

```
set /p bom=<%YUI_FOLDER%\bom
```

which I am unable to understand what this line do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set /p var=[prompt]` is the usual way in batch files to retrieve input from the user, showing a prompt (if present) and storing the user response in the variable.

`set /p` reads its data from a stream, usually the console, but a pipe or a redirection can be readed in the same way.

In this case, the `set /p` will read its data from a redirected file. The `<` is a input redirector operator. It indicates that the stream to read from will not be the console, but a file indicated after the operator.

In this case the file is called `bom` and is located inside a folder. The path to this folder is stored in the environment variable `%YUI_FOLDER%`

So `set /p bom=<%YUI_FOLDER%\bom` means: *read the content of the file `bom` from the folder referenced in the variable `%YUI_FOLDER%` and store the data retrieved into the `bom` variable*

`set /p` will retrieve data from the file until the end of file, a end of line or the read buffer is full, what happens first.

Answer (score -1):

In [this script](http://forums.mp3tag.de/index.php?act=attach&type=post&id=3594) I found an annotated piece of code which pretty much explanes what the line should do:

```
REM Unicode transformation.
REM Report files should be readable in Windows Notepad editor.
REM Example DOS characters: ”„á‚
REM Example WIN characters: öäüßé
REM Create Unicode files with BOM.
REM Having set the current codepage to 1252, ...
REM then the UTF-16LE BOM can be created by the command ...
REM SET /P BOM=ÿþ<NUL 2>NUL >"UnicodeFile.txt"
```

So, in the [YUI Compressor Bash Script Manager](http://www.3site.eu/yuibompressor/) this line is used to create the variable `bom` which is checked whether it is `utf8` or `cp1252` or whatever...